# Bouncing image balls with KineticJS

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I'm just starting out the KineticJS library and been playing about with it creating shapes etc.. However, I'm struggling to create a custom circle with my own image in it. I have tried using the fillPattern but it doesn't scale/centre correctly at all. Am I meant to use my own circle image or a rectangle image and then let KineticJS take care of things?

Just to give a bit of background: What I want is 3 balls bouncing in and then settling in place.

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it... needed the offset values

```
          var ball = new Image();
          ball.src = 'ball2.jpg';
          ball.height = 230;
          ball.width = 230;

              var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                  container: 'container',
                  width: 1000,
                  height: 1000
              });

              var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
                  x: 300,
                  y: 300,
                  radius: 115,
                  fillPatternImage: ball,
                  fillPatternOffset :{
                      x: -115,
                      y: -115
                  }
              });

              var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

              // add the shape to the layer
              layer.add(circle);

              // add the layer to the stage
              stage.add(layer);

              ball.onload = function () {
                  stage.draw();
              }
```